# On a brand new MacBook Pro, a regular trackpad click does not work

Tags: macbook, touchpad

My brand new MacBook Pro is failing to click. Just like that, everything else works — two-finger right-click, keyboard — everything works. But a plain old regular trackad click just fails to respond.

Resetting things doesn’t help: Resetting the computer, resetting the PRAM, resetting the NVRAM. Nothing.

I’m posting this here, just because I think something might have had a similar thing happen, and I’ve wasted quite a bit of time dealing with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the question - no fix I could find helped (including advise to click on the Apple logo on top-right of the screen in order to shutdown the computer and restart it).

The problem was that I had an external trackpad connected, and somehow it was powered on. Something was pressing it, so my trackpad click was always pressed and never released.

Comment: Decent self-solved question! This might seem like a very basic issue, but sometimes in tech people tend to forget the basic stuff.